# Can't Expose My Docker Container To My Mac Localhost

Tags: linux, docker, nuxt.js

Can you check the grammar of the following Dockerfile and Docker Compose? I can't connect to my localhost using my Mac. Is there something wrong with it? I'm using Nuxt.js as my framework.

Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  parents:
    build:
      context: ./parents
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - ./parents:/app
```

Here's my parents Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 make g++

RUN python3 -m ensurepip

RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools

RUN echo $PYTHON

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the entire project directory to the container
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Comment: The `volumes:` block can lead to confusing and inconsistent behavior, and I'd probably delete it; I'd use the shorter `build: ./parents` syntax; and I'm a little confused why you need Python and a C compiler in a Node image.  But nothing you show is obviously related to connecting to a process from the host.  What URL are you trying to connect to?  From where?  What is the main process running in the container?